# Bootstrap 4: hide overflow in card-text

Tags: overflow, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 card in which I want to hide the overflow of the subtitle (and show "..."). How can I achieve this? If possible with pure bootstrap code...

```
<div class="card-block p-1">
    <p class="card-title">Test object</p>
    <p class="card-subtitle text-muted">Added by Someone with a long name</p>
    <p class="card-text mx-auto text-center"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">€ 800</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the `text-truncate` util class..

```
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block p-1">
      <p class="card-title">Test object</p>
      <p class="card-subtitle text-muted text-truncate">Added by Someone with a long name</p>
      <p class="card-text mx-auto text-center"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">€ 800</span></p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/bZufg6X1So

Comment: I was using bootstrap4-alpha-6 and I had some workarounds in my card-columns which caused problems with your solution. So I will start using bootstrap 4 beta first and hope some problems are solved (then your solution will definitely work)...

Comment: Ok, so I tested with Bootstrap 4 beta, but problem still exists... I still have to add "display: inline-block" to the card class to prevent cards from splitting over columns. But this fix seems to break the text-truncate solution... See this codeply (https://www.codeply.com/go/EgoBGlw9xA) --> Card with pioneer DJM 850 isn't shown correctly in a viewport of 520x... or less

Comment: i'm not really seeing an issue in Chrome, but css multi columns is inconsistent across browsers. Either way the original question of text ellipsis  has been answered.

Comment: Is there a way to truncate or ellipsis after 3 or 4 lines rather than on the first line itself?