# Bootstrap 4 collapse panel with preview and overflow expansion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement this seemingly [simple bootstrap setup](https://medium.com/@beedaan/partial-collapse-with-bootstrap-3-ef4e6bf85537) with [example](https://codepen.io/beedaan/pen/JWNWXa/) that shows a small preview for overflowing text and adds an expandable panel for the overflow. The problem is it was designed for BS3 and I need BS4 for the cards. It's not working the way I have it, and I'm not sure if it is incompatibility with BS3/4 or not, because even when I use the BS3 CDN (`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`), it doesn't work like it does in the example... not even close, no button, no text, just the title 'Bacon Ipsum'.

To be honest, I'm not great with HTML, JS, CSS and CDNs... so I may be way off. If I'm not using the right CSS or JS CDN, let me know. The only thing I changed was the div id to a class. I have accomplished something similar with accordion classes, but nothing exactly like this with a preview and a single section for text (not one for a preview and another to show when expanding).

index.html: (edited with style.css loaded last and JS CDNs at the bottom of the body section)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="module">
        <h3>Bacon Ipsum</h3>
        <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false">
          Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner picanha tri-tip biltong leberkas salami meatball tongue filet mignon
          landjaeger tail. Kielbasa salami tenderloin picanha spare ribs, beef ribs strip steak jerky cow. Pork
          chop chicken ham hock beef ribs turkey jerky. Shoulder beef capicola doner, tongue tail sausage short
          ribs andouille. Rump frankfurter landjaeger t-bone, kielbasa doner ham hock shankle venison. Cupim
          capicola kielbasa t-bone, ball tip chicken andouille venison pork chop doner bacon beef ribs kevin
          shankle. Short loin leberkas tenderloin ground round shank, brisket strip steak ham hock ham.
        </p>
        <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample"
           aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
.module {
    width: 500px;
}

.module p.collapse[aria-expanded="false"] {
    display: block;
    height: 40px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.module p.collapsing[aria-expanded="false"] {
    height: 40px !important;
}

.module a.collapsed:after  {
    content: '+ Show More';
}

.module a:not(.collapsed):after {
    content: '- Show Less';
}

body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }

.bs-example {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

If I can combine this with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694288/bootstrap-4-hide-overflow-in-card-text) for ellipses, that would be great!

**UPDATE**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="module">
        <h3>Bacon Ipsum</h3>
        <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false">
          Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner picanha tri-tip biltong leberkas salami meatball tongue filet mignon
          landjaeger tail. Kielbasa salami tenderloin picanha spare ribs, beef ribs strip steak jerky cow. Pork
          chop chicken ham hock beef ribs turkey jerky. Shoulder beef capicola doner, tongue tail sausage short
          ribs andouille. Rump frankfurter landjaeger t-bone, kielbasa doner ham hock shankle venison. Cupim
          capicola kielbasa t-bone, ball tip chicken andouille venison pork chop doner bacon beef ribs kevin
          shankle. Short loin leberkas tenderloin ground round shank, brisket strip steak ham hock ham.
        </p>
        <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample"
           aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.module .collapse, .module .collapsing {
  height: 3rem;  /* [NUM_OF_LINES] x [LINE_HEIGHT] */
}

.module .collapse {
  position: relative;  /* For ...'s content absolute positioning */
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module .collapse:before {
  content: ' ...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.module .collapse.show {
  height: auto;  /* You need to reset the height when not collapsed */
}

.module .collapse.show:before {
  display: none;  /* Of course you don't want to display ... */
}

.module a.collapsed:after {
  content: '+ Show More';
}

.module a:not(.collapsed):after {
  content: '- Show Less';
}
```

CSS was copied directly from jfiddle example. The html is placed in actual html tags and while I'm not using a card in this example, the collapsible panel would be inside said card.

This is outputting:

[image]

I can see the main (and collapsed) text in the source, but it is not visible. Please let me know if there is other diagnostic information that would be helpful. Obviously you're solution works from the example provided, but something isn't right here. If it matters, this will be rendered through a django template.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're using one of the (unsupported) Alpha versions of Bootstrap 4? You're better off using the current version - https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Like I said, terrible on the frontend. Thanks for the link. Tried swapping it in but no difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Your `<div>` element is invalid as it has multiple class attributes: `class="module"` and `class="container"`. The first class declaration will override all subsequent values so your `<div>` will only have `module` class.
2. You don't have to target only `<p>` with `[aria-expanded="false"]`. You can make it more generic by removing those in the CSS.
3. You need to reset the height when the collapsed element is showing. Bootstrap 4 uses a CSS class called `show` so you can write CSS for that to reset the height.
4. To display ellipses style for text overflow, normally you can just use the CSS3 `text-overflow` with `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;`. However, `text-overflow` only works on a single line of text. To hack it around, you have to use absolute positioning for the `...` content.
5. In the demo, I am showing 2 lines of text when collapsed. To calculate the height, I just used [NUM_OF_LINES] times [LINE_HEIGHT], which is 1.5 in bootstrap. That's how I came up `3rem` for the height.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="module">
        <h3>Bacon Ipsum</h3>
        <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false">
          Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner picanha tri-tip biltong leberkas salami meatball tongue filet mignon     
          landjaeger tail. Kielbasa salami tenderloin picanha spare ribs, beef ribs strip steak jerky cow. Pork 
          chop chicken ham hock beef ribs turkey jerky. Shoulder beef capicola doner, tongue tail sausage short 
          ribs andouille. Rump frankfurter landjaeger t-bone, kielbasa doner ham hock shankle venison. Cupim 
          capicola kielbasa t-bone, ball tip chicken andouille venison pork chop doner bacon beef ribs kevin 
          shankle. Short loin leberkas tenderloin ground round shank, brisket strip steak ham hock ham.
        </p>
        <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" 
         aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.module .collapse, .module .collapsing {
    height: 3rem;
}

.module .collapse {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.module .collapse:before {
    content: ' ...';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.module .collapse.show {
    height: auto;
}

.module .collapse.show:before {
    display: none;
}

.module a.collapsed:after {
    content: '+ Show More';
}

.module a:not(.collapsed):after {
    content: '- Show Less';
}
```

#### Structure

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Demo

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/cu0p613v/

Comment: Thank you for your solution and demo! I'm certain this is the way to go, but something is still not registering correctly. Please see update above with page output. Maybe I am not calling the correct CDNs in the correct way. Thanks.

Comment: Also wanted to add I might have messed something up. Before I was able to work with the collapse panels and accordions, but now none of that is rendering either and I can't get it to work even with the 4.0-alpha version I had before. I think it is the CDN link/version I am using. Above is what I have.

Comment: Well, when you run your app, does your console have any error? Maybe screenshot your developer tool / console by pressing F12 when you run your app?

Comment: Done, see new screenshot with dev console open and the collapse div highlighted; it doesn't appear covered up and neither does the button. No errors at all in the console. If you want me screenshot something else that would be more helpful, just let me know. I am at your disposal and grateful for your help.

Comment: You need to load your `style.css` last. Otherwise other css classes will overwrite the custom styles. Also it's good practice to put all your javascripts at the end of the `<body>` tag not in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Turned out the problem was the ordering of my CDNs. Needed jquery first, popper second, and bootstrap last. Looks great. Thanks! As a last question, was curious to know how much more modding would need to be done to make it so the 'show more'/'show less' only appears if the text is too long for the div without the div size increasing through CSS/HTML, or if that is more suited to do via scripting.

Comment: @user58446: don't think you can achieve that just by using pure CSS. Maybe somebody else who has more knowledge could confirm that. I think you might have to use jQuery plugin like this one: http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly the look the asker wants, but this might help others.

You can set a clickable div above all your text, with a transparency transition making it "fade away":

[image: Collapsible div with fade]

It will partially show whatever is in inside the div up to the height defined in the `.module .collapse` CSS

It consists of a relative module parent and an absolute `.read-more` :

```css
.module {
  position: relative;
}

.module .collapse,
.module .collapsing {
  height: 7rem;
}

.module .collapse {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module .collapse.show {
  height: auto;
}

.read-more {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 60%, white);
}

.read-more:not(.collapsed) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.module {
  position: relative;
}

.module .collapse,
.module .collapsing {
  height: 7rem;
}

.module .collapse:not(.show) {
  display: block; /* By default the bootstrap collapse has a display: none */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module .collapse.show {
  height: auto;
}

.read-more {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /* 60% is where it should start the transition from transparent to white, increase it if you want to show more of your text */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 60%, white);
  
  /* The opacity and transition is just to smooth out the effect */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.read-more:not(.collapsed) {
  opacity: 0;
  /* If you want to make the clickable area disapear once it is open, change the visibility to hidden */
  /* visibility: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="module">
  <a class="read-more collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button"></a>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false">
    <h3>Bacon Ipsum</h3>
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner tongue cow frankfurter hamburger rump salami tail. Ham chuck pork chop turducken filet mignon, sausage pancetta capicola. Alcatra ribeye shank tri-tip boudin. Beef ribs tenderloin bresaola tongue, salami hamburger ham boudin
      pork belly sausage. Chuck beef boudin drumstick doner ball tip. Cupim filet mignon hamburger, pork loin ground round cow ribeye t-bone shoulder pastrami kielbasa corned beef pork chop strip steak. Chislic kielbasa picanha sirloin shankle short
      ribs jerky prosciutto andouille short loin.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/lucaskuhn/pen/OJNgdPv

Comment: This is a nice example, but the CSS rules seem to be unnecessarily duplicated in some places?